# Custom hook returning a promis

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it possible to return a promise from a custom react hook and await for it? Like:

```js
const getData = useMyCustomGetDataHook();

const fetchData = async () => {
  await getData({...props});
  // ... do stuff..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly `await` for a promise while rendering (aside from [the experimental suspense stuff](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)).

You could use e.g. [`useSWR()`](https://swr.vercel.app/) as a wrapper for a promise-returning function (which, wink wink, could be e.g. something that uses `fetch()`...).

```
async function getData(x) {
  return x * 4;
}

function useData(x) {
  return useSWR(['myData', x], (_, x) => getData(x));
}

function MyComponent() {
  const dataSWR = useData(8);
  if(dataSWR.data === undefined) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }
  return <>{dataSWR.data}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality, there is no such thing as a custom React Hook - it is simply a fancy name for a function having a name that starts with `use`. Thus, any function can be a custom React Hook - including a function that returns a `Promise` that you can `await`.

However the real problem is that your async function won't be usable inside a component. `render()` is not async and you cannot await. In fact a custom React Hook is more about the programming paradigm that the function itself.

What you need to do in your case is to launch your async operation either from `useEffect()` - if it does not require that DOM is created, or from `useLayoutEffect()` - if it requires it - and then trigger a state change in the `.then()` handler. This is the *React way* of doing this.

Comment: That's _not_ the React way. You aren't allowed to launch a side effect directly from an FC's body (or a class component's `render()` method). React is allowed to (and will) call the render function at will. You will need to use `useEffect()`, or if you need the DOM, `useLayoutEffect()`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am editing my answer.